# How to make a shape move with the arrow keys?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, class, keyboard

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int vx = 5;
    int vy = 5;
    int bx = 0;
    int by = 50;
    int px = 93;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 100;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    public class Ball
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public int W;
        public int H;

        public Ball(int x, int y, int w, int h)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            W = w;
            H = h;
        }
    }

    public class Paddle
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public int W;
        public int H;

        public Paddle(int x, int y, int w, int h)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            W = w;
            H = h;
        }
    }

    public class Brick
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public int W;
        public int H;

        public Brick(int x, int y, int w, int h)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            W = w;
            H = h;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int[] brickxs = { 0, 51, 102, 153, 204, 255, 306, 357, 408, 459, 510, 561, 612, 663, 714, 765 };
        int bc = 0;
        SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        Ball b = new Ball(55, 55, 25, 25);
        Paddle p = new Paddle(93, 377, 130, 30);
        Brick br = new Brick(20, 20, 51, 20);
        br.X = 0;

        while (bc < 16)
        {
            br.X = brickxs[bc];
            System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics;
            formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            formGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, new Rectangle(br.X, 0, 49, 20));
            myBrush.Dispose();
            formGraphics.Dispose();
            bc = bc + 1;
        }

        Rectangle ball = new Rectangle(bx, by, b.W, b.H);
        Rectangle paddle = new Rectangle(px, p.Y, p.W, p.H);
        //Rectangle brick = new Rectangle(br.X, br.Y, br.W, br.H);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(blueBrush, ball);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(blueBrush, paddle);
        //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(blueBrush, brick);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Right)
        {
            px += 5;
        }
    }

    private void MoveTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bx = bx + vx;
        by = by + vy;

        if (px <= 0)
        {
            px = 0;
        }

        if (px >= 771)
        {
            px = 771;
        }
        WallCollision();
        floorandCeilingCollision();
        Invalidate();
    }

    public void WallCollision()
    {
        if (bx >= 771)
        {
            vx = -5;
        }

        if (bx <= 0)
        {
            vx += 5;
        }
    }

    public void floorandCeilingCollision()
    {
        if (by >= 420)
        {
            vy = -5;
        }

        if (by <= 0)
        {
            vy = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

I am creating a game and I need some help.

In my code have classes for each of the parts of the game: the ball, paddle and bricks. The array positions the bricks.

I want to move the paddle (which just a rectangle) left and right with the arrow keys. I tried to use the key down method but it did not work.

Could you suggest any solutions or point out anything that I left out?

Comment: This code needs too many changes to make it functional. You have to start removing this: `System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics; formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();` and use just the `e.Graphics` object provided by the Paint event. Create you `Paddle` and `Ball` just once. The `brickxs` array, too. Declare fixed Brushes outside the Paint event and dispose of these when the Form closes. I don't know what `MoveTimer_Tick` handles. I assume you have two timers that try to create a different speed for Ball and Paddle. Try to assign meaningful names to your Fields/Variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I use e.KeyCode instead of e.KeyData, try this first.

Make sure your Form is focused, and not a picturebox or something else you might have in the game. Because you try to call the KeyDown event for your Form, not for a control inside your Form.

I never used a Paint event, are you sure it is called? It might be the case that your game registeres the movement but never shows the changes to you. I usually have a separate method for drawing and I call it every time there is a change, you should try this too.

If nothing works, try debugging. Set a break point in your KeyDown method to see if it is called. If it does, set it in the Paint method. This one will surely be called once, at runtime, but if you click "Continue" on that time and try to move your object. If it is not called any other time, then here is your answer :)

Please update me with what you find after trying this things, and ask me what to do next if you get stuck or simply don't know what else there is to do :)